# Finding example of a compact metric space a non hausdorff Topological space and a continuous function that maps X onto Y

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

This question is from my topology assignment and I am struck on it.

> Give an example of a compact metric space $(X,d)$ , a topological space $(Y,\mathcal{U})$ that is not Hausdorff and a continuous function $f$ that maps $X$ onto $Y$.

Topological space can be taken $Y=\mathbb{N}$ under usual topology. But I am not able to decide $(X,d)$ as compact so that a continuous function exists.

If I take Euclidean metric $d$ then I have to take a closed and bounded subset but I am not able to then find a continuous function then.

Kindly guide!

Comment: $\Bbb N$ with the usual topology **is** Hausdorff.

Comment: Please edit your Question to clean up the wording of the title and notation, spelling, punctuation, etc. in the body.  You've asked a couple of hundred Questions here, so it's not unrealistic to expect attention to details.

Comment: Why not take any compact metric space $(X,d)$ (with more than one point) and let $Y=X$ with the trivial topology $\mathcal U=\{\emptyset,Y\}$? So $(Y,\mathcal U)$ is a non-Hausdorff topological space, and it shouldn't be hard to find a continuous function that maps $X$ onto $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You know that the continuous image of a compact space is compact, so $Y$ must be a non-Hausdorff compact space. An easy way to make sure that $Y$ is compact is to make it finite. We need at least two points in $Y$ if it is to be non-Hausdorff, so let’s let $Y=\{0,1\}$ and $U=\{\varnothing,\{0\},Y\}$. $[0,1]$ is a nice compact metric space; we can try to find a continuous function $f$ mapping $[0,1]$ onto $Y$. What has to happen in order for $f$ to be continuous? We need $f^{-1}[\varnothing]$, $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$, and $f^{-1}[Y]$ to be open in $[0,1]$. Two of those are automatically true; which two? Now find a way to define $f$ so that the third is true as well **and** $f$ is surjective (onto), and you’ll be done.

Comment: $Y$ is [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Yep. Very useful little fellow, that space is.

Comment: I used it to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3956825/compact-subset-of-a-compact-topological-space)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think f(x) $\equiv 0 $ will do? Am I right

Comment: @No-One:  that's not surjective

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Can you tell how to construct 1 such function?

Comment: @No-One: Here’s a further hint: when defining $f$, consider the subsets $\left[0,\frac12\right)$ and $\left[\frac12,1\right]$ of $[0,1]$.