# Compact subset of a compact topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact topological space and $K$ be a compact subset of $X$. I want to prove that $K$ is a closed subset of $X$, or not. I tried to show that the complement of $K$ in $X$, is open. But, I am not able prove that. I also tried to show that $K$ contains all its limit points. If $K$ is not closed in $X$, please give an example.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think this is true for Hausdorff spaces, but not for infinite sets with the cofinite topology; cf. answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239998/compact-sets-are-closed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: An infinite set in the cofinite topology gives a $T_1$ counterexample. Each of its subsets is compact.

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample, let $K$ be the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), whose underlying point set is $\{0,1\}$

and whose open sets are
$ \{\varnothing ,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$.  Since $K$ is finite, $K$ is compact.

The subset $\{1\}$ is compact but not closed.

Comment: Much simpler example: In indiscrete topology all subsets are compact but non empty proper  subsets are not closed.

Comment: Thanks for the example.